# Showing a Lipschitz function is differentiable

Tags: analysis, lipschitz-functions

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a Lipschitz function.  Suppose 
$$ \lim_{n\to \infty} n[f(x + \frac{1}{n}) - f(x)] = 0.$$
Prove that $f$ is differentiable.

I am tempted to just let $n = \frac{1}{h},$ then $$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = 0,$$

meaning that the limit exists and therefore $f$ is differentiable.  However, I feel like the issue may be more subtle than this.  Could someone give a more rigourus proof that might not involve using $n = \frac{1}{h}?$

Comment: The trouble with your argument is that $\frac{1}{h}$ might not be an integer.  Perhaps try rounding it to an integer and using the Lipschitz property to deal with the rounding error.

Comment: Why would $\frac{1}{h}$ have to be an integer in the first place?

Comment: "meaning that the limit exists and therefore $f$ is differentiable" ... and constant.  Seems a little strong.  All we normally expect is that the (magnitude of the) derivative is essentially bounded by the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: For $f$ to be differentiable, it is necessary that $\lim \frac{f(x + a_n) - f(x)}{a_n}$ exists for _any_  sequence $a_n$ such that $\lim a_n = 0$. Your assumption only holds for one specific $a_n$, namely $a_n  = 1/n$. You need to prove that Lipschitz-continuity along with the limit existing for this _single_ $a_n$ implies the limit exists also for _all other_ $a_n$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Knowing the limit $\frac{f(x+h_n)-f(x)}{h_n} \to 0$ along a single sequence $h_n = \frac{1}{n}\to 0$ is not enough to be able to conclude that the limit along all possible sequences $h_n\to 0$ exists and is equal zero (which is needed to prove differentiabillity).

---

To solve the problem let $[h]$ denote the closest number to $h$ on the from $\frac{1}{n}$ with $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and write: $$\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h} = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x+[h])}{h - [h]} \cdot \frac{h-[h]}{h} + \frac{f(x+[h]) - f(x)}{[h]}\cdot \frac{[h]}{h}$$ Now take $h\to 0$. The first term can be bounded using the [Lipschitz condition](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LipschitzCondition.html), $\frac{|f(x)-f(y)|}{|x-y|}\leq C$, and the second term can be bounded using the given limit. You also need to show that $\frac{h-[h]}{h}\to 0$ and that $\frac{[h]}{h}$ is bounded as $h\to 0$ to reach the desired conclusion but this is fairly straight forward from the definition of $[h]$.

Comment: Before marking this correct, why is it that this $[h]$ needs to be brought in in the first place?  Also, I assume in the first line it was meant "closest number to $h$ of the form $n = 1/h,$ where $n \in \mathbb{N}$...".

Comment: @Merkh The Lipschitz condition only says that the derivative (if it exists) is bounded. Thus we must somehow use the other condition to be able to prove the result. This is a condition for $h$ on the form $h = \frac{1}{n}$ only. This is what motivates introducing $[h]$ which is on this form. The definition is such that $[0.49] = \frac{1}{2}$ and $[0.3] = \frac{1}{3}$. We can compute $[h]$ by finding the closest integer $n$ to $\frac{1}{h}$ and then $[h] = \frac{1}{n}$. For example $\frac{1}{0.3} = 3.33$ and the closest integer to this is $3$ so $[0.3] = \frac{1}{3}$.